# With JPA can I have a field in Class A be OneToOne to Class B and then a field in Class B be OneToOne to Class A?

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-one

I have 2 classes where Class A has a non-null field that is a OneToOne of Class B.

Now I am looking to have a field in Class B that connects to one of the Class A Instances.

For example, lets say a Person is taking books out of the Library.  Each Book would have a OneToOne to the User and that wont change; however the User has a field that connects to only one of the Books called `CurrentlyReadingBook` and that could change.

The Initial OneToOne of storing the person object into the Book's user field is fine, but when I try to do the OnetoOne of storing the book into the person object I'm getting a Stackoverflow error, to which I assume is due to the 2 classes just calling each other back and forth trying to get the data infinitly.

So I am wondering if what I am trying to do is possible by only using 2 separate Tables/Classes?  I thought about having a Table C and then just putting the information in there, or storing just the ID of the Book instead of the Book Object itself, but I feel that these 2 methods are unnecessary, I would think there should be a way to do it only Using the 2 Tables/Classes I have.

Thank you very much for any information/help.

Here is the error in case this helps in some way

```
 Info:   Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [PersistenceUnitA] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [PersistenceUnitA] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(A --> [DatabaseTable(A)])
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(B --> [DatabaseTable(B)])
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(C --> [DatabaseTable(C)])
Exception [EclipseLink-168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Problem in creating new instance using the default constructor.  The default constructor triggered an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(D --> [DatabaseTable(D)])
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Frame challenge: If it's 1-to-1 and not optional, why isn't it just a single table?  If it needs to be 2 tables, why don't they share a single key field?  Two distinct key fields for 1-to-1 just adds unnecessary headaches.

Comment: The 2 Tables each have their own corresponding set of information that is separate from each other. i.e., book has pages, book number, etc, person has id, name, numbooks, etc  There might be 15 books, each connected to a person (the same person or different people), but each person might be reading 0 or 1 of the books they have, meaning that field in the Person Table could be blank, or be filled with one of the Book Objects (Note the books/person is an example and not what I'm actually doing).  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm not exactly familiar with what you mean by "Sharing a single key field" and what that entails? Thank you for the information.

Comment: The error you get is in your constructors, not JPA; looks like you have the constructor for a book create a user and the user constructor call the default book constructor, causing the recursive loop.